# How to make a timer that ticks down in c# monogame

Tags: c#, timer, monogame

So I'm trying to make a timer that will ticks down from 30 seconds to 0 in monogame but I don't understand how I can do it. I'm very new to programing. I'm trying to put it into my enum so when the timer hit 0 it will change state from play to gameover.

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed ||                
        Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
        Exit();
    
    switch (currentGameState)
    {
        case Gamestate.Start:
            timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            if (timeSinceLastFrame >= timeBetweenFrame)
            {
                timeSinceLastFrame -= timeBetweenFrame;
                currentFrame.X++;
                if(currentFrame.X >= sheetSize.X)
                {
                    currentFrame.X = 0;
                    currentFrame.Y++;
                    if (currentFrame.Y>=sheetSize.Y)
                    {
                        currentFrame.Y = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            posStone.Y = posStone.Y + 1;

            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
            {
                currentGameState = Gamestate.Play;
            }

            break;
        case Gamestate.Play:

            


            break;
        case Gamestate.GameOver:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I'm trying to put it into my enum so when the timer hit 0 it will change state from play to gameover"_ -- put what into what enum? And where in the code above are you trying to change the game state back to `GameOver`? Your question is unclear, and doesn't provide evidence of what you've tried so far. Please improve it.

Comment: Likely referring to switch statement when it is said * I'm trying to put it into my enum * but yes the question needs to be clarified.

Answer (score -1):

### Method 1

This approach I used in a game where I was storing a future DateTime representing the world game time with a future starting point and updated on every Unity physics frame in my Monobehaviour script. However the general idea can be used in your scenario. If you don't need to store the game time between saves then this might be overkill. Read *Method 2* in that case.

You store an end time and a reference time (game time) for the game's current time. You'd want to store both as a class property.

```
DateTime referenceTime;
DateTime endTime;
```

Right before you set *currentGameState* to *Gamestate.Play* you would want to set these values

```
referenceTime = DateTime.Now; //Would be assigned from a global GameTime class object or your own custom game time
endTime = referenceTime.AddSeconds(30);
```

Then you would update your reference time on every physics frame. I used Millisecond instead of Seconds for accuracy ([GameTime Documentation](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime.html)) since in most game engines I've worked with frames updates tend to happen in a fraction of a second. This would be placed under *Gamestate.Play* case branch

```
referenceTime.AddMilliseconds(gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Then you also would need to do the check in the same case branch (probably after the last code snippet).

```
if (referenceTime > endTime) {
    currentGameState = Gamestate.GameOver;
}
```

### Method 2

GameTime class has an alternative member *totalGameTime* which is also a System.TimeSpan struct value ([GameTime Documentation](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GameTime.html), [TimeSpan Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1)). So this means another option is you can used the total number of seconds from the beginning as the game time. The reference value would be again stored as a class member it is now an *int* this time since we will store the number of seconds since the game started.

```
int referenceTime;
```

You would set the reference time right before you switch *currentGameState* to *Gamestate.Play* . There are other ways of doing this but this is probably the simplest.

```
referenceTime = gameTime.totalGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

Then you would add a check in your *Gamestate.Play* case statement as such. If you plan on repeatedly using *gameTime.totalGameTime.TotalSeconds* then you might want to store it in another variable for legibility.

```
if (gameTime.totalGameTime.TotalSeconds > referenceTime + 30) {
    currentGameState = Gamestate.GameOver;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked into [System.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netcore-3.1) class?

An example of the class is below so you can copy and paste into LinqPad to run and experiment with.

```
void Main()
{
    /* What this does is raise an event every 5 seconds, according to value set in the interval
    */
    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(5000);
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    timer.AutoReset = true; // Whether or not the event should be repeated
    timer.Enabled = true; // Starts the timer
}

void OnTimedEvent(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                          e.SignalTime);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post "link-only" answers. The salient content should be in the answer itself and you should only link to provide supporting evidence for that content. In this case you should demonstrate how the OP can user `System.Timer` to solve their issue.

Comment: Oh I see, good call. Thanks for the clarification, I'll edit my response now!

Comment: How does the code you posted here demonstrate to the question's author how to _"put it into my enum so when the timer hit 0 it will change state from play to gameover"_? I don't see any mention in this answer of enums, the timer reaching `0`, or a change in game state. You seem to have completely failed to address _any_ of the specifically stated goals of the question.

Comment: Ah that's fair, I gave an example on how to use timer but it would have probably been better to write an example of a countdown instead. 

Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: This would only work if GameTime corresponds to System Time with no pauses or different factors. Would be a short solution! Should mention where the Timer should be created (right before transition of *currentGameState * to *Gamestate.Play*  and make the parameters relevant to the question (eg. AutoReset not needed) . Also the OnTimedEvent body is simply *currentGameState = Gamestate.GameOver;*.